# Semantic externalism and transitivity of causal chains (using Putnam's brain-in-a-vat thought experiment)

Tags: semantics, skepticism, realism, hilary-putnam, brain-in-a-vat

**TL;DR: I'm looking for information on semantic externalist views on transitivity of causal chains. Is it an objection anyone has invoked? Does it hold? What are potential pro-Putnam responses to it?**

Putnam writes in "[Reason, Truth and History](https://philosophy.as.uky.edu/sites/default/files/Brains%20in%20a%20Vat%20-%20Hilary%20Putnam.pdf)" about the brain-in-a-vat thought experiment. He argues semantic externalism is true and that words refer to things in the actual, existant world (a realist position) if and only if there is an appropriate causal chain of reference. He uses the following metaphor:

> "An ant is crawling on a patch of sand. As it crawls, it traces a line in the sand. By pure chance the line that it traces curves and recrosses itself in such a way that it ends up looking like a recognizable caricature of Winston Churchill. Has the ant traced a picture of Winston Churchill, a picture that depicts Churchill?
> Most people would say, on a little reflection, that it has not. The ant, after all, has never seen Churchill, or even a picture of Churchill, and it had no intention of depicting Churchill. It simply traced a line (and even that was unintentional), a line that we can 'see as' a picture of Churchill."

This is extrapolated into a claim that the sentence "I am a brain in a vat" is false if we are not brains in a vat (BIVs). If we **are** BIVs, there is no causal chain of reference for our use of "brain" and "vat". In our language, they refer to our ideas of brains and vats. This may not be similar enough to the actual brains and vats that we may be in. If it is, it is coincidence (like the ant example). Therefore it is always false.

In an essay attacking this position, I brought up the claim following claim. Given that we are BIVs:

1. The simulation fed to our brains may have a designer.
2. The designer may design the simulation to reflect his world.
3. There is an appropriate causal chain between our use of the words "brain" and "vat" and simulated brains and vats.
4. There is an **intentional and appropriate** causal chain between simulated brains and real brains, and between simulated vats and real vats.
5. Causality is transitive. If A caused B and B caused C then A caused C.
6. Therefore there is an appropriate causal chain between our use of the words "brain" and "vat" and real brains and vats.
7. Therefore we are correctly referring as per semantic externalism.
8. Therefore the sentence "I am a brain in a vat" is true if we are BIVs in a simulation designed to mimic reality.

I hope you see that the first two premises are a feasible hypothetical that disturbs Putnam's claims of irreferentiality, and that premises 3 and 4 are generally accepted causal chains. To provide an example for why 3, 4 and 5 are in my view true:

> Jake has never heard of Harald Hardrada. He decides to play Sid Meier's Civilisation VI, and sees Harald Hardrada as a playable character. His use of the words "Harald Hardrada" has an appropriate causal chain to the simulated Hardrada, and the simulated Hardrada has an appropriate causal chain to the real one. By transitivity Jake is correctly referring to Harald Hardrada when he says "Harald Hardrada".

I mean, if you deny this premise upon which my core argument rests then I think it could result in a *reductio ad absurdum* in which I argue you cannot refer to any historical figure (as you only see "simulations" of them in whatever media format).

Is transitivity of causal chains a commonly accepted property? If so, has anyone made this argument or potentially attacked it? Does it successfully counter Putnam's claims on "I am a BIV" being irreferential?

Comment: Norzick had some relative distance modal trick to retain BIV's real metaphysical possibility via being remotely referential to our actual world but it's not counted as our actual knowledge. Davidson in his "World without Reference" rejected any possibility of any language-independent real metaphysical referentiality or meaning via his radically charitable contextualization without any ontological commitment burden, while your version has designer commitment...

Comment: You say the designer feeds to us the information that we are BIVs; is that correct?

Comment: @TankutBeygu No; instead the designer has made the simulation realistic enough for our perception of brains and vats to refer transitively to real brains and vats (even if we do not know they exist).

Comment: A BIV already believes by its nature that it is a real brain in a body (that is, without any question about this occurring to it). I think you ought to expand on "reference to real brains and vats," perhaps illustrating it by cases, like supposing that there are an X which is a BIV and a Y which is a real brain (living in a world within a body).

Comment: @TankutBeygu I think you're misunderstanding my argument. It doesn't matter if the BIV believes they are a BIV or not. In my hypothetical, there is an X which is a BIV and a Y which is not only a real brain but the designer of vat-world. The question is about transitive reference, not whether the BIV can find out they're a BIV. It is about if the transitive reference gained could allow the BIV to genuinely refer when they say "I am not a BIV" and thus go against Putnam's argument that the statement is irreferential.